# How to build an scala sbt project as Android library?

Tags: android, eclipse, scala

I have an SBT Android project from open source community that I can build it and run it on the phone without problem. Now I want to turn it into a Library, so that I can reference it in my another regular Android project, call some of it's classes, make them work with my own code.

I'm an experienced Android developer working with ADT, but I'm a newbie of Scala and SBT. I know in ADT project it is so easy that just add android.library=true to project.properties to make the project a library. But what should I do with an SBT project?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know it is to create a [multi project build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html) config.

[Here](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/tree/master/sbt-test/android-sdk-plugin) you have some samples.